# How to remove Decimal from SQL select statment

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MHSE_ AS INT) AS MHSE_ from [EnterpriseGIS].[gisdba].[TAXPARCEL]
```

This is my statement but the result comes like

> 4959.000000

I wanted to show

> 4959

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried using `CONVERT(int, MHSE_)` to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: What tool are you using? It might just be an display setting in your environment. Is it not SSMS?

Comment: I tried convert and cast did not work but FLOOR worked . thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what DBMS you are using but you could try using the [FLOOR()](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/floor-wth-positive-value.php) function like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FLOOR(MHSE_) AS MHSE_
FROM [EnterpriseGIS].[gisdba].[TAXPARCEL]
```

Here is the description of the `FLOOR` function:

> The SQL FLOOR() rounded up any positive or negative decimal value down to the next least integer value. SQL DISTINCT along with the SQL FLOOR() function is used to retrieve only unique value after rounded down to the next least integer value depending on the column specified.